# Can I cut out a blister in my drywall joint and add more tape to the small section?

Tags: drywall

The only reason I am asking is because i used Durabond and getting the tape fully off of this small 6" section is going to likely damage the drywall. With 50 inside corners and a ton of butt seams i missed a few small blisters. Any advice?

I removed the tape from 1 blister and had to dig and scratch at it. Got the tape and then some. Wondering if a 2nd piece of small tape is OK. the air pocket would be gone of course

Comment: pierce them and mud over, you'll be fine.  A bit tongue in cheek, a pic or two would help us help you.   Also, take the tour so you'll know best how to participate here.  Welcome to SE.

Comment: [The aforementioned tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: I like the sticky mesh tape because it doesn't blister https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8h23XltAsE

Answer (score 1):

I like to get some mud under the tape, if not painted just cut it lay it back add mudd and put it in place and work it flat.
If painted I use a big syringe and push some mud in there work it around and press the air out Ends up looking like a small nail hole but works really well when going in on a poorly done job that you don’t want to spend a lot fixing up.

Answer (score 0):

For a section that short I wouldn't bother with tape. I usually make football-shaped cuts and peel out the loose area, then just skim. It's unlikely to crack with anything under 6 inches.